# How to send Email from android application without installed an email application

Tags: java, android, email, send

I have question. I've go an E-mail application but when I press the send button I must have at least one E-mail application installed. Code:

Java file:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    final EditText adress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
    final EditText subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
    final EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    ImageButton send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , adress.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , message.getText().toString());
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setTitle("Mail");
                builder.setMessage("Mail send sucessfully.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Finish.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        adress.setText("");
                        subject.setText("");
                        message.setText("");
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

**Please help me.**

Comment: Why not authenticate to an SMTP server and send from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user does not have an email application installed on the phone, you can take the user to the `PlayStore` and request him to download an email app of their choice (or one that you recommend).

The other option is having your own SMTP server using which you can send emails.